# node.js passport user schema set it manualy

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, session, passport.js

first sorry for my english ;) 
second my question :

describtion :
I have :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }
});
// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

to use it with passport on a node.js .

...

```
var User = require('../app/models/user');
```

i dont connect to mongodb , since i use mysql to store my sessions .

the only stuff i dont understand  is the _id value , comes it from passport , or sessions ?

question :
what i have todo  to get a user model (object) so it is working together with passport/session ? or are there some method i need anyway , so it is better to get the user model from mongoose  ?

sincerley rakondark

Answer (score 0):

The id (known as the ObjectId) is generated and set by MongoDB for each documents.
I believe it auto-increments while using MySQL for passport.